# How to show progressbar synchronized with playing video?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I have used this code to load the video from url

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        //Use a media controller so that you can scroll the video contents
        //and also to pause, start the video.

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(LandScapeTv.this); 
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
        videoView.start();
```

It's working fine but while playing video it shows nothing for moment i.e. it's buffering , can anybody suggest the solution to how to sync progressbar with loading video?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to just google "progress bar android" instead of making this post?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin yeah..it's very easier, my question was How to show progressbar synchronized with playing video

Comment: your question does not make sense, first you ask how to make a progress dialog to show that the video is loading and then you change it and want to know how to sync a progress bar with the video. which is it

Comment: @RahulMatte - You question title should be relevant to want you need. I have edited your question. Please check